# hr within table but full width

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I made this block of code

```
  <table>
    {item.awards.map((obj,i) => 
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>{obj.title}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>{obj.award}</td>
        </tr>
        {i !== item.awards.length-1 ? <hr /> : ''}
    </tbody>
    )}
  </table>
```

It worked, every block has a separator (`<hr/>`) but the problem now is the hr length is not full width. I can't make the table 100% as it will effect the td.

Comment: can we have a fiddle or any link to see your problem?

Comment: I think this is invalid HTML. The children of `<tbody>` have to be `<tr>`, you can't have `<hr>` there.

Comment: `<tr border-bottom="1px solid black">`

Comment: As before, a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) would make it much easier to help you. (And as before: Note that Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).)

Comment: @Barmar so what is ur solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's invalid to have an `hr` as a direct child of `tbody`. `tbody`'s [content model](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tbody-element) only allows `tr` elements (and scripts). Even if it seems to work in one browser, there's no guarantee it will in another, or even in the next dot rev of the one where it used to work.

So you need to put the `hr` in a `tr`, which means putting it in a `td` or `th`:

```
{i !== item.awards.length-1 ? <tr><td colspan="3"><hr /></td></tr> : null}
```

You can then style the `hr` as necessary with CSS to make it as wide as you like. For instance (note the `sep` class on the separator rows and the CSS it applies to the row and the `hr`):

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.sep hr {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -0.1em;
}
.sep {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>{obj.title}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>{obj.award}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sep">
      <td colspan="3">
        <hr />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>{obj.title}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>{obj.award}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sep">
      <td colspan="3">
        <hr />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>{obj.title}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>{obj.award}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

(Side note: `null` is a better choice than `''` for the third operand of that conditional operator.)

Comment: She wants the `<hr>` to be the full width of the window, not just the table.

Comment: @Barmar: As I said, apply CSS styling as needed. I've added an example of one possible CSS setup, but of course, it depends on what she really wants, which is only vaguely hinted at. :-)